# Eliminar dato de un modal sin cerrarlo

Tags: jquery, json, modal

necesito si me pueden ayudar, tengo un modal que me trae la informacion que necesito, mi problema se genera cuando quiero eliminar una imagen que he subido, la cual me esta eliminado y cerrando el modal y necesito que si elimino la imagen, el modal quede abierto y no se cierre.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código cuando armo el modal es el siguiente:

```
$('.detalle').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sit = $(this).attr('href');
            url="{{route('verDetalle', ["id"=>"#REF#"])}}";
            url=url.replace("#REF#", $(this).attr('ida'));
            $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#formModal').attr('action', sit);
                $('#modalDetalle').modal('toggle');
                if(!data.Estado){
                    alert("Error");
                }else{
                    $('#nombre').html(data.nombre);
                    $('#fecha').html(data.fecha);
                    im = "";
                    $('#imagen1').html('');
                    urlI = '{{route('eliminar', ["id"=>"#ID#"])}}';
                    urlI=urlI.replace("#IDPD#", data.idd);
                    if(data.url1!=""){
                        im+='<div class="form-group">';
                        im+='<label>Imagen</label>';
                        im+='<br>';
                        im+='<a href="'+data.url1+'">';
                        im+='<img src="'+data.url1+'" width="200" height="200">';
                        im+='</a>';
                        im+='<a href="'+urlI+'" class="btnDelete">';
                        im+='<i class="icon-trash"></i>';
                        im+='</a>';
                        im+='</div>';
                    }else{
                        im+='<div class="form-group">';
                        im+='<label>Subir</label>';
                        im+='<input type="file" name="archivo1" class="form-input-styled">';
                        im+='</div>';
                    }
                    $('#imagen1').append(im);
                    im = "";

                    im2 = "";
                    $('#imagen2').html('');
                    urlI2 = '{{route('eliminar', ["id"=>"#ID#"])}}';
                    urlI2=urlI2.replace("#IDPD#", data.idd);
                    if(data.url2!=""){
                        im2+='<div class="form-group">';
                        im2+='<label>Imagen</label>';
                        im2+='<br>';
                        im2+='<a href="'+data.url2+'">';
                        im2+='<img src="'+data.url2+'" width="200" height="200">';
                        im2+='</a>';
                        im2+='<a href="'+urlI2+'" class="btnDelete">';
                        im2+='<i class="icon-trash"></i>';
                        im2+='</a>';
                        im2+='</div>';
                    }else{
                        im2+='<div class="form-group">';
                        im2+='<label>Subir</label>';
                        im2+='<input type="file" name="archivo1" class="form-input-styled">';
                        im2+='</div>';
                    }
                    $('#imagen2').append(im2);
                    im2 = "";
                }
            });
        });
```

En mi controlador, la variable uriI y urlI2 llaman a la siguiente ruta, que es el código de eliminar:

```
    public function getDelete($id, Request $request){
        $doCommit=true;
        $errmesg="";

//Bueno, aca tengo un código más extenso, porque también elimino la imagen del S3
        
        $det= Detalle::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        if($det==""){
            $doCommit=false;
            $errmesg.="Dato no existe.";
        }else{
           $det->delete();
        }

        return response()->json(array("Estado"=>$doCommit, "Errmesg"=>$errmesg), 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

¿Como puedo lograr que al presionar el basurero el modal no se me cierre y quede abierto? Ayuda por favor

Comment: Ese código que pones no parece corresponderse con el del icono de eliminar. ¿Estás seguro de que se trata de ese trozo de código?

Comment: Los datos que traigo en el json son los que muestra el modal, hasta el momento lo tengo asi, tal como se ve, cuando presiono el basurero llama a urlI, editaré y pondré mi código del controlador cuando elimino, pero sucede que al apretar el basurero se ejecuta la acción pero se me cierra el modal, y necesito que quede abierto

Comment: Necesito que mi modal se recargue al eliminar la foto, me imagino que hay algo que el codigo no estoy poniendo, pero no se como hacerlo, ayuda porfis